# SharePoint keyboard shortcuts not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sharepoint

According to MS documentation, these are the keyboard shortcuts for SharePoint:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-SharePoint-products-7dec847a-4f2a-47f6-9964-0ea1fba45160?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__toc335125097

But the 4 shortcuts mentioned in the "List or library page" section isn't working.

I've tried SP13, SP16, Foundation/Server, through IE11 and Chrome, but can't get them to work. Nothing happens when I press the keys listed in the documentation.

Anyone knows what's going on?

Thanks :-)